# How to add application specific attributes to Profile using Pac4J with Google2Client?

Tags: google-signin, profile, pac4j

I am working on a JEE 8 application, where i want to use Googles authentication mechanism (OAuth2) for an easier registration process of new users.

This is my project setup:

- deltaspike 1.9.5
- pac4j 3.8.3 (using Google2Client)
- Java 11
- Wildfly 23

the client is initialized in the following way:

```
Google2Client google2Client = new Google2Client();
google2Client.setKey("API_KEY");
google2Client.setSecret("API_SECRET");
google2Client.setScope(Google2Scope.EMAIL_AND_PROFILE);
google2Client.setName("google")
```

Can somebody please give me a hint where i could enhanced the authorized user profile,
that is returned by the google2client with attributed, that are necessary for my application?
I found some pieces of information, that a ProfileCreator could be used somehow.
I would be very happy, getting some examplecode. This would also help others to support
pac4j (its a great framework).

kind regards

Shane

**UPDATE**

I solved it by extending OAuth20ProfileCreator

```
public class MyCustomProfilecreator extends OAuth20ProfileCreator {

    @Override
    protected void addAccessTokenToProfile(OAuth20Profile profile, OAuth2AccessToken accessToken) {
        
        super.addAccessTokenToProfile(profile, accessToken);
        profile.addAttribute("testkey", "testvalue");
        }

    public CustomProfilecreator(OAuth20Configuration configuration, IndirectClient client) {
        super(configuration, client);
    }
}
```

and then set it in the google client:

```
String mycallbackurl = BaseUrl + "/mybackend/resources/callback?client_name=google";
google2Client.setCallbackUrl(mycallbackurl);
google2Client.setKey(KEY);
google2Client.setSecret(SECRET);
google2Client.setScope(Google2Scope.EMAIL_AND_PROFILE);
google2Client.setName("google");
google2Client.setProfileCreator(new MyCustomProfilecreator(google2Client.getConfiguration(), google2Client));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Java 11, you should use pac4j v5.7.1: https://www.pac4j.org/docs/alldocs.html

For the `Google2Client`, the `OAuth20ProfileCreator` relies on the `Google2ProfileDefinition`: https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/5.7.x/pac4j-oauth/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oauth/profile/google2/Google2ProfileDefinition.java

You can see in this class the logic and retrieved attributes.

Comment: thank you for this hint - i solved it based on you (see UPDATE of original post)